# Ideal generated by two polynomials is maximal

Tags: ring-theory

Let $P_{1}(x)$=$x^{2}$-1,$P_{2}(x)$=$x^{3}$+$\lambda$, for which $\lambda\in R$ (necessary and sufficient condition)the ideal in R[x] generated by $P_{1}(x)$,$P_{2}(x)$ is maximal.

I started by finding the factorization of the first polynomial, dividing by all the possible cases of common factors between the polynomials, each such case gives a condition on the Lambada, and for each such case check if the gcd is reducible. Is that the direction?

Comment: $(x+\lambda)(x^3+\lambda)+(1-\lambda x-x^2)(x^2+1)=\lambda^2+1$ for any $\lambda$, so $<P_1(x),P_2(x)>$ is maximal if $\lambda^2+1$ is prime?

Answer (score 0):

Solution. In order to ensure that ideal generate is maximal we need first to make sure that the $gcd(p_{1},p_{2})$ is a prime (irreducible) this will tell us that the ideal is maximal, first note that the euclidean algorithm will not work because we have no $\lambda$ in our hand, instead we know that $x^{2}-1$ is reducible and $x^{2}-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ so, we want to find $\lambda\in R$ in which $x^{3}+\lambda=(x-1)(x+1)g(x)$where $deg(g(x))=1$ recall $g(x)=ax+b$ so, $x^{3}+\lambda=(x-1)(x+1)(ax+b)$

$(x^{2}-1)(ax+b)=ax^{3}+bx^{2}-ax-b$

In this case, we have that so we get that $b=-\lambda=0$ and $a=0$ so no such a $\lambda$. Now, suppose that we have $g(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c$ in which $deg(g(x))=2$ s.t.,$x^{3}+\lambda=(x-1)g(x)$ so we get that, $x^{3}+\lambda=(x-1)\left(ax^{2}+bx+c\right)$
$=ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx-ax^{2}-bx-c$
$=ax^{3}+(b-a)x^{2}+(c-b)-c$

Note that, $a=1$ and $c=-\lambda$ where $b-1=0$,$c-b=0$ hence, $a=1,b=1,c=1=-\lambda\Rightarrow\lambda=-1$. Therefore, $g(x)=x^{2}+x+1$

which is irreducible

(in contradiction that g is not irreducible then there must be polynomial $ax+b\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ in which $a\neq0$ s.t $ax+b\mid g$ so we must get that $x=-\frac{b}{a}$ is root but g has no root in R because its means that $g(x)=0$ because g(x)>0 we can show that by taking any $x>1$ or $x<-1$ or $0<x<1$ if x>1 or x<-1 then obvious otherwise $x^{2}+1>x$ for all -1<x<1).

Now, again, we need to find $g(x)=ax^{2}+bx+c $ where $deg(g)=2x^{3}+\lambda=(x+1)(ax^{2}+bx+c)$ (continue...)

so in total $\lambda=\pm 1$